# GAE PHP - image (.jpg) file not found on the server

Tags: php, image, google-app-engine, app.yaml

My image file is not found on the server. I declared it as static on my `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /sampleimage\.jpg
  static_files: sampleimage.jpg
  upload: sampleimage\.jpg
```

As you can see it's on the root directory, I tested it first on localhost and it is found:

`localhost:8080/sampleimage.jpg`

However when deployed on the web it's not there:

`http://samplesite.appspot.com/sampleimage.jpg`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here because my `favicon.ico` which is also static file is working fine `http://samplesite.appspot.com/favicon.ico`.

complete `app.yaml`:

```
application: samplesite
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /
  script: index.html

- url: /sampleimage\.jpg
  static_files: sampleimage.jpg
  upload: sampleimage\.jpg
```

Comment: What does your complete app.yaml file look like? Maybe one of the earlier handlers is overriding this handler?

Comment: @IanGSY nothing much really I'm just testing, I've added the complete contents of my `app.yaml`. pls help thanks.

Comment: I just changed the `.jpg` to `.JPG` and It's now found.

Comment: Yes, filenames are case sensitive on AppEngine.